# How to add a form in add-in in powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on PowerPoint 2007 and after I created a form and while saving it as ppam I got an error as "You can't add form in ActiveX controls".

So is there is any round about way to do the same ?

Please advice.

Comment: Please always post the EXACT text of any error messages whenever you request tech support, whether here or elsewhere.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg : Hi steve, i also encountered same error in my project. The error is "Powerpoint couldn't compile the visual basic for Applications code associated with this presentation". It popups when i try to same my project as .ppam format.

Comment: @Pratik, that sounds like a different problem than what Matthew's reported.  Try compiling the project before saving it as PPAM.  That will normally put it in debug mode with the problem line of code highlighted. It might help you too, Matthew

Comment: @SteveRindsberg : it works while compiling but gives above error when trying to save as ppam format.

Comment: One or modules may have become corrupted.  Try exporting each module to a frm/bas/cls file, then start a new presentation and import the modules back into it.  See if that compiles and saves to PPAM.

Comment: Had the same problem as @PratikGujarathi. Solved by following these steps to compile the project: (1) Open the PPT. (2) Switch to the Visual Basic Editor. (3) Select Debug | Compile VBA project. The compilation will fail on the line containing the error. Thanks @SteveRindsberg!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after copy-pasting a macro code I had saved elsewhere into my Powerpoint project. I got the same error message

> Powerpoint couldn't compile the visual basic...

I solved this by following the steps that commenter Skovly left underneath the original question:

1) Open the Visual Basic Editor (F11, or Developer -> Visual Basic)

2) Menu: Debug --> Compile VBA project

The cursor will indicated places in the code that make trouble. In my case these were series of blanks that for some reason were read as part of expressions that weren't complete. This must have come somehow from the place where I had stored the macro code before pasting it into the VBA module. After deleting these blanks (empty lines), I could save the .ppam as desired.